# Capturing Application exit event - WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Is this possible to capture Windows form close event when clicked on application stop.
I know application stop working but is there any method available who will fire in any case when application is closing?
I found these methods from google but they are not working:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);
```

or

```
  Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit);
```

Is it possible to get close event when click on application stop button?

Comment: You mean closing browser? You need to check javascript onUnload method() or onbeforeunload() method.

Comment: what you mean by asp.net windows forms? ASP.Net running on WinForms?

Comment: Let's see if I have this straight.  A.) Your program is crashing, or not responding, so you have to close it with task manager or something, and you still want an event to fire before it closes.  Is this correct.  Or B.) Do you simply want an event to fire when the program ends normally?  What, exactly is an application stop button?

Comment: .NET has WinForms while ASP.NET has WebForms

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Program.cs file, you must have those methods **before** Application.Run :

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

You can also use the Disposed event on the MainForm (the form used in Application.Run method).