# How can I manage the way my application closes?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to close my application in the same way, whether it is closed directly or closed from task bar or task manager. I need to do some pre-settings and automatically generate log files each time before the application is closed...

For example I give following effect to my application form each time it exits, but this effect is not shown when I close my application from task bar or task manager...

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer closeTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    void lblClose_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        closeTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(closeTimer_Tick);
        closeTimer.Interval = 10;
        closeTimer.Start();            
    }

    void closeTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = (int)(this.Opacity * 100);
        a--;
        this.Opacity = ((double)a / 100);
        if ((this.Opacity*100) == 0)
            this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps this question will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579446/capturing-application-exit-event-winforms

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Form` has two events `FormClosing` and `FormClosed` you can use in this situation.

Comment: @PLB That will only captured the form closing - which does not necessarily mean the application is closing.

Comment: @Mansfield Yes, right. I forgot to mention http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx

Comment: Just do all this code behavior in the event that is thrown when the application is being closed.  Do understand there are some ways to close an application where this event is NOT thrown, so you better realize that, and handle the situation where the what you expect to happen has not happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your app is a System.Windows.Forms.Application.  If so you can listen to ApplicationExit event.

So in Main, do something like:

```
Application.ApplicationExit += (s,e) =>
{
   // Your exit code.
};
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx

Answer (score 5):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10579614/1324019):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

This is preferable to using `FormClosed` as just because a form is closing does not necessarily mean the application is (specific to your code of course).

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle `FormClosing` event. 
More info here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx

Comment: As I said in the comments, this offers no guarantee that the **application** is closing, only the form.

Comment: @Mansfield - There are also lots of ways to close the application in such a way the ProcessExit event is also not thrown.

Comment: @Ramhound by rudely terminating the process, yes. It's not infallible - but it is better than using FormClose. I misused the word guarantee, I admit.