# Disposing ActiveX resources when application is force-closed via Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a WinForms project that uses an `ActiveX` control.  I can hook into Form close events to ensure I release these resources when the application is closed normally, but if I'm running in debug mode in Visual Studio and have to force the application closed with the stop button, these resources are never released.

I've tried hooking into `Application.ApplicationExit`, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`, and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload`, but none of these seem to fire if the application is killed via the stop button.

Is there a way I can ensure all my resources are disposed of when stopping an application through Visual Studio?

Comment: This is normal, the hazard of using an out-of-process server.  It doesn't know that your client app quit without saying goodbye nicely so it has no reason to stop running.  You can wait 10 minutes to let Windows take care of it.  Not practical of course, keep Task Manager handy.

Comment: You could try this method:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579446/capturing-application-exit-event-winforms