# Action before terminating app

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I am developing a standalone app and need to do some action(Exactly I need to post some request on some URL) when user loggs out the system..

I've tried to achieve this with `Application.ApplicationExit` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`  events or with destructors but non of this seems to work.

I would be grateful for some hint on how to do it.

Here is some snippet from my main function:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    ...

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.ApplicationExit += Application_ApplicationExit;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += Application_ApplicationExit; 
    Application.Run();
}

static void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.Create("C:\\kod\\test5.txt");
}
```

I am trying to test this behaviour with creating file(easier to see the results).

Hope this time it will be more clear.

Comment: Without *any* indication what your code looks like, this would be too broad. Add more details so your question does not get closed. Is there a reason you cannot do whatever you want to do as the last lines of your `main` method?

Comment: "user loggs off" have many meanings, but rarely used in relation to WinForms... Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: If "logs off" == "application exit" than this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579446/capturing-application-exit-event-winforms

Comment: Hope this time it is more clear

Comment: What exactly happens? Is the file not created? Can you put a breakpoint in `Application_ApplicationExit`?

Comment: The file is not created. I quite don't see how could I put a breakpoint while logging out.

Comment: Because you can't guarantee the file operation will complete before the application exits.

Comment: Your question is more like how to delay shutdown (check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5217246/1997232)).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Using some advice from You guys I came up with a satisfactory solution.

I've created a minimized, not showing in the taskbar form(so it is invisible for the user) and overriden 
the WndProc when I run some code on `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` and `WM_ENDSESSION` messages.

And some code:

```
public class BlockingForm : Form
{
    public delegate void SessionEnd();
    public event SessionEnd SessionEndEvent;

    public BlockingForm()
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message aMessage)
    {
        const int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x0011;
        const int WM_ENDSESSION = 0x0016;

        if (aMessage.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION || aMessage.Msg == WM_ENDSESSION)
        {
            OnSessionEnd();
        }

        base.WndProc(ref aMessage);
    }

    private void OnSessionEnd()
    {
        var handler = SessionEndEvent;
        if (handler != null) handler();
    }
}
```

Mostly helpful comment was the one from @Sinatr. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

To make visible your Windows Form you need to pass the Form object in Application.Run() method.

```
Application.Run();
```

.
[Application.Run Method: Begins running a standard application message loop on the current thread, without a form.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900(v=vs.110).aspx)

pass the form to make it visible.

```
Application.Run Method (Form)
```

Comment: But i dont want to have a visible form.