# Ask confirmation message only once from user in C# Window Appliaction

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i built an windows application using c# .

On form closing event i wrote a code like this to ask confirmation form user...

```
private void Approve_User_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to QUIT application...?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }
```

sometimes it ask four times , even upto five times....

I want this only once if user press Yes then application should exit.

I need your help and suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are subscribing to this `Approve_User_FormClosing` event in a place which execute a few times. If you subscribe 4,5 times it will execute 4,5 times.

If you just want to capture application exit event have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579446/capturing-application-exit-event-winforms) thread.

**Edit**

You need something like below to achieve your weird requirement.

```
private bool isExiting = false;

private void Approve_User_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isExiting)
                   return;

            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to QUIT application...?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                isExiting = true;
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: @Waqas: Can you show you subscribe this event? And how many Forms do you have in this application?

Comment: I have 14 forms in my app and i don't know about subscribe and unsub.. Will you please guide me..?

Comment: @Waqas: What are you trying to achieve? What's the requirement? Do you want to confirm before exiting the application?

Comment: Yeah... when user click on (X) button to close application then system ask him/her to confirm and if user press Yes on message box then application should exit ... Now clear?

Comment: @Waqas: Do you handle this  form close event in multiple forms? It should be only in the Main form.

Comment: @Waqas: You should handle it only on the Main form. That will fix your issue.

Comment: and then what about if user wants to close application from another form other than main?

Comment: @Waqas: Is it possible at all?

Comment: @Waqas: I think you have missunderstood something. You can exit the application only if you close main form. If you close the main application it will exit the application anyway. Do you say you want to close the application from other forms too?

Comment: yeah... is it possible or not?

Comment: That's a weird behavior. However it is possible. The issue here is you will see a message box for each Form that is open by the time user close one such form. So, the solution is setting a Public static bool IsExiting in your main form and stop displaying this message if it is already shown to the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84991/discussion-between-waqas-and-charithj).

Comment: now i write code on main form and redirect user from all forms to this main form and now i got two confirmation messages on form closing event .. what would you suggest now

Comment: @Waqas: As I suggest before you need a boolean flag to indicate that if this messagebox is shown to user once. If so, don't show it again. Public static bool IsExiting = false; And set it to true when you show your confirmation box once.

Comment: bro i just add Application.ExitThread(); then now it works perfectly.. thanks for your suggestions and time